# How to call an activity method from an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

When I launch my App it closes directly. I have been searching but I have not found how to fix the problem.

Have you an idea to fix the problems?

```
public class AsyncBigCalculActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mButton;
    private TextView data;
    private String dataImplode;
    PostTask PostTask = new PostTask(this);
    public AsyncBigCalculActivity activity;

    public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Telephone: "+phoneNumber+"\n Message: "+message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        // On récupère les composants de notre layout
        data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLaunch);

        // On met un Listener sur le bouton
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    PostTask.execute();
            }
        });         
}

       // The definition of our task class
       private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

           private AsyncBigCalculActivity activty;

       public PostTask(AsyncBigCalculActivity activty) {
          this.activty = activty;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();

       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          return getServerData("http://site.com","etat","nok");
       }

       @Override
       protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
          super.onProgressUpdate(values);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);

          if(result != null || result.length()>0){
              String[] res = result.split(";-;");
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res[0]+"\n"+res[1]+"\n"+res[2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              activity.sendSMS("0000000000", "Hello World !");  
          }

       }
       }


private String getServerData(String returnString,String post, String valeur) {
        String Num ="";
        String Message ="";
        String Id ="";

        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(post,valeur));

        // Envoie de la commande http
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(returnString);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convertion
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Parsing 
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Num = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("destinataire_mobile");
                Message = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("destinataire_message");
                Id = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                dataImplode = Num+";-;"+Message+";-;"+Id;

                if(((Num.length())==12) && (((Message.length())>=2)) && Num != "" && Message !=""){





                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(Message);
                    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(Num, null, parts, null, null);

                    getServerData("http://site.com","id",Id);
                }

            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return dataImplode;         
    }
}
```

Error Logcat:

```
01-21 14:05:45.978: I/global(7218): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
01-21 14:05:49.788: D/HtcBuildUtils(7218): NetworkOperator: 20801
01-21 14:05:49.788: D/HtcBuildUtils(7218): NetworkOperator: 20801
01-21 14:05:49.788: D/HtcBuildUtils(7218): NetworkOperator: 20801
01-21 14:05:49.788: D/HtcBuildUtils(7218): NetworkOperator: 20801
01-21 14:05:49.788: D/SmsManager(7218): General sendMultipartText
01-21 14:05:49.908: I/global(7218): In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection
01-21 14:05:50.098: E/log_tag(7218): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-21 14:05:50.108: D/AndroidRuntime(7218): Shutting down VM
01-21 14:05:50.108: W/dalvikvm(7218): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a5c228)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at com.arnaud.AsyncBigCalculActivity$PostTask.onPostExecute(AsyncBigCalculActivity.java:111)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at com.arnaud.AsyncBigCalculActivity$PostTask.onPostExecute(AsyncBigCalculActivity.java:1)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5005)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-21 14:05:50.118: E/AndroidRuntime(7218):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! I can see that you have trouble to use SO in the right way. If you want to append something to your question please click on edit right under your question. Please read also the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `PostTask` constructor never gets called. This occurs because you're calling `PostTask.execute()` without instantiate `PostTask`.

Here's two solutions:

You could replace `activity.sendSMS` to `AsyncBigCalculActivity.this.sendSMS()` on your `onPostExecute` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if(result != null || result.length() > 0){
        String[] res = result.split(";-;");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res[0]+"\n"+res[1]+"\n"+res[2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AsyncBigCalculActivity.this.sendSMS("0000000000", "Hello World !");  
     }
}
```

or simply call `new PostTask(AsyncBigCalculActivity.this).execute()` on your `onClick` method.

Comment: That's nice ! The App work fine ! :D Thanks you *Marcos Lopes*.

Have you an idea why when I click once everything works but when I reclick, the App closes directly ?

Comment: `Have you an idea why when I click once everything works but when I reclick, the App closes directly ?` No. Edit your question, and post your new logcat error.

Comment: on `if(result != null || result.length() > 0){` replace `||` operator to an `&&` operator. And, if you think my answer is correct mark as accepted. Thanks.